# Raku: Installation of Termbox on Windows

Tags: raku, zef

Installation of the Raku module «Termbox» module fails on windows:

```
Powershell> zef install Termbox
Failed to find dependencies: python:from<bin>.
```

I have installed Python (v3) on the pc, but that does not help.

Is it possible to fix this, so that the module can be installed?

(And also, will the module actually work with Powershell?)

Answer (score 5):

You can ignore a dependency via `--exclude=Foo`, so:

```
zef install Termbox --exclude=python
```

(there should probably be a note in that error message about this option)

Will that module actually work with PowerShell once getting past that step? I think the real question is does it actually work on Windows period, and for that I don't have an answer.

Comment: Thanks. That took me a little further. And then it fails with: 'gmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Choco has a 'make' package, which is gnu make, but installing that does not help.

Comment: That is presumably from the Termbox module's Build.pm script, which is using the LibraryMake module, which is getting the make used to build rakudo (`raku -e "say $*VM.config<make>"`).

Comment: Ok. I installed Raku with choko (as recommended here: https://www.learningraku.com/2018/01/18/hints-for-perl-6-on-windows/), so have no build environment on the windows pc. That probably means that I would have to build Raku manually, before trying to install Termbox. I am not a windows-person, so I don't know if I want to try all that just to see that it fails (as i suspect that it will).